# Icon hidden when I add padding in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have this design in Sketch.

[image]

And my code for designable for applying padding to text in the text field as shown below.

```
@IBInspectable var paddingLeftCustom: CGFloat {
    get {
        return leftView!.frame.size.width
    }
    set {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
        leftView = paddingView
        leftViewMode = .always
    }
}

@IBInspectable var paddingRightCustom: CGFloat {
    get {
        return rightView!.frame.size.width
    }
    set {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
        rightView = paddingView
        rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

But when I apply padding to text, the image on the left get hidden as shown in the below image

[image]

I will appreciate your answers, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the designable code to

```
@IBInspectable var leftImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0
```

And applied my padding via the storyboard.